# List Comprehension with Instances

Tags: python, list, instance

I am trying out list comprehension and I am stuck with the below problem.

```
class Programmer():
    def __init__(self, name, years_at_umich=1, programs_written=0):
        self.name = name
        self.seniority = years_at_umich
        self.bonus_points = random.randrange(1000)
        self.programs_written = programs_written

    def shout(self, phrase_to_shout):
        print phrase_to_shout  # print is for ppl!

    def __str__(self):
        return "My name is {}, and I've been at UMich for about {} years.".format(self.name,self.seniority)

    def year_at_umich(self):
        return self.seniority

prog_tups = zip(names, seniority,programs_written)
print prog_tups
```

prints output

```
[('Albert', 1, 10), ('Bisi', 5, 500), ('Cai', 2, 20), ('Dinesh', 4, 131), ('Euijin', 1, 46)]
```

I am trying to use list Comprehension to create a list of Programmer instances out of the prog_tups list from above and save that list in the variable programmers.

My current code is below, I am not getting a traceback, but nothing happens:

```
programmers = [item for item in prog_tups]
```

Comment: `programmers = [item for item in prog_tups]` is just copying `prog_tups` in `programmers`... you probably need to _print_ `programmers` to get an output...

Comment: What do you mean Programmer instances? Where is the Programmer class?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, in such case, he could just `print names`(as it contains a programmers names)

Comment: yes, I think he wants to create a `Programmer` object. but first things first. Lesson #1: `print` statement...

Comment: We need to know more about your `Programmer` class to answer this question. Can you add the type signature of your `Programmer` constructor (```def __init__(self, ...)```)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if you don't have a custom `Programmer` class yet consider using [***collections.namedtuple***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) subclass:

```
import collections

Programmer = collections.namedtuple('Programmer', 'name seniority programs_written')
prog_tups = [('Albert', 1, 10), ('Bisi', 5, 500), ('Cai', 2, 20), ('Dinesh', 4, 131), ('Euijin', 1, 46)]
programmers = [Programmer(n, s, p) for n,s,p in prog_tups]

# the first programmer
print programmers[0]
```

The output:

```
Programmer(name='Albert', seniority=1, programs_written=10)
```

---

To deal with your existing custom class, use the following approach:

```
prog_tups = [('Albert', 1, 10), ('Bisi', 5, 500), ('Cai', 2, 20), ('Dinesh', 4, 131), ('Euijin', 1, 46)]
programmers = [Programmer(*t) for t in prog_tups]

# the first programmer
print programmers[0]
```

The output:

```
My name is Albert, and I've been at UMich for about 1 years.
```

Comment: Awesome that did the trick, thank you. Also I edited my code to add the Programmer class.

Comment: @Avery9115, welcome, also, see my update to deal with your custom class

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a list of only the names. Seeing as the names are the first element in the tuples, a simple solution would be `programmers = [item[0] for item in prog_tuples]` to obtain only the names. To see if this works, simply `print()` it.